# Github Copilot not launching with VSCode

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, github-copilot

I am on Linux and I use VS Code, every time I restart VS Code, Copilot is just not there. In Output, it doesn't show up either, so I am pretty sure it is just not starting. I am logged into GitHub and the GitHub Authentication seems to be successful. I have Copilot as part of the Developer Students pack.

I tried uninstalling and installing other versions, it didn't help, the only thing that helps is deleting the extension folder and then reinstalling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone has the same issue, check your AV, I was using Clam AV, and it somehow detected copilot as virus and removed parts of the extensions content. Adding an exclusion solved my issue.